# How does uksort() process an array internally

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

After working on [this question](/questions/7829754/how-to-perform-a-custom-sort-on-an-array-and-preserve-keys) for quite a while, I've realized that I don't fully understand how uksort works internally and can't find any documentation to that effect.

What order are the values processed, and does further processing for a value stop when you return an integer value for the current comparison?

Comment: Most (all?) PHP functions that operate on a whole array start at the beginning and work to the end, ignoring the array pointer (like `foreach` would). If you call `return` *anywhere*, regardless of context, further processing within that context stops. I think there are no exceptions to this rule. I am not, however, posting this as an answer because I don't know these things for absolute 100% definite.

Comment: PHP's open source - you can grab that and see exactly how uksort's implemented: http://php.net/downloads.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order the values are processed in is up to the interpreter's sorting algorithm. The upshot is that you shouldn't worry about it; the end result will be the same no matter what order they're processed in (if you sort of deck of cards it will end up in the same order whether or not you shuffled it beforehand as long as `2 < 3` and `J < Q` and so on).

In all but the most naïve sort algorithms a value will be visited ("processed") several times before arriving in its final place in the result array. When you `return` in the callback you supply to `uksort` that is not necessarily the last time the callback will be called for those two values.

Comment: So if I write a sort function that just returns 0 for every comparison the end result should be exactly the same array just like in your deck of cards example?

Comment: Not necessarily. Some sorting algorithms are ["stable,"](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Stable_Sort) i.e. they will return equal items in the same order they were given, and others aren't. As of version PHP the sorting algorithm used by PHP is not stable.